# Ruby on Rails, validate datetime before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a form_for which give me two datetime format (start and end dates). My goal is to check that end_date > start_date.

In my model I don't know how to do that, here is what I did so far (not working) :

```
class XXX < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :check_dates

  private

    def check_dates
      if self.end_date > self.start_date //I don't know how to do it
    end
end
```

Error :

```
syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Thanks

Comment: why not `self.end_date` and `self.start_date`?

Comment: Yes but this is not my actual variable name, it's more a syntax request :) Anyway I correct my post

Comment: @ZazOufUmI what's the issue? This should work

Comment: What is the Error? Also what do you want to do after checking the dates? Is it validation or control sequence?

Comment: @Mandeep I have a syntax error I did not know how to say in rails language : If end_date > start_date it's ok, ELSE raise an error and redirect to form_for page

Comment: You have a syntax error because you are not ending your `if` statement!! If this is a validation I suggest you use rails validation helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mandeep's answer is comprehensive and covers what you want. I just want to add if you are looking to use this validator in other models you can create a validator model:

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.end_date > record.start_date
      record.errors[:base] << 'End date should be greater that start date!'
    end
  end
end

class XXX < ActiveRecord:Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```

The code is from rubyonrails.org: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: This one is OK but when an error occured it redirect me to root path without displaying any message

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because inside your callback you only have a condition, *you didn't specify what to do when this condition evaluates to true also you didn't close your if statement hence a syntax error. Although your callback will also do the same thing but in your case i think it'll be better if you use a validation instead*

```
class XXX < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_dates

  def check_dates
    errors.add(:base, "end date should be greater than start") if self.end_date > self.start_date //I don't know how to do it
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `validate :check_dates` than `before_create`

Comment: @Arijoon yeah i was just updating it